# Need downcasting clarification

Tags: c++, downcast

I do not quite understand how to downcast. Apparently I can not do it like this...

```
class myType
{
};

class otherType : public myType
{
};

int main()
{
    myType* obj = new myType;

    otherType* castObj = dynamic_cast<otherType*>(obj);

    delete obj;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you're trying to cast from "smaller" type to "wider" type, it is not downcasting

Answer (score 0):

Some clarification I think, is needed.

when class B is derived from class A, the following holds:

- a B is an A
- an A is not necessarily a B

if you are holding a pointer to A, you can check whether it is the A-part of a B by attempting to dynamic_cast to a B. If that cast succeeds, it is because you were actually pointing to the B's A interface. If the cast does not succeed then the A-like thing you were pointing at was not actually a B.

So:

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A();
};        // a base class

struct B : A {};    // a B is an A but an A is not necessarily a B

A* pa = new A;
// pa is pointing to an A

B* pb = dynamic_cast<B*>(pa);
// pb will now be NULL because this cast will have failed.
// Remember, a B *is an* A, but an A *is not necessarily a* B

delete pa;

// try again...
pa = new B;
// pa points to the A-part of a B, so

pb = dynamic_cast<B*>(pa);
// pb now points to the same object, but has access to all the methods on the B interface

delete pb;
// clean up
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I like to explain this to my girlfriend:

Something being a **car** means that it definitely has **wheels**.

Something having **wheels** does not necessarily make it a **car**.

Say we have classes:

```
class A
```

and

```
Class B: public A
```

The `Class B` surely has all the traits of the `Class A` and probably some more, but we can always safely convert it (cast it) to the `Class A` by simply "removing" all the additional things it carries, 
**which** is not true the other way around: we cannot be **certain** that the `Class A` will have **the same traits** as the class you're trying to cast it to, in this case `Class B`. This is why you have to use the `dynamic cast`, to inform the compiler that you're aware of the risk this ensues.

> If the cast is successful, dynamic_cast returns a value of type new_type. If the cast fails and new_type is a pointer type, it returns a null pointer of that type. If the cast fails and new_type is a reference type, it throws an exception that matches a handler of type std::bad_cast.

Comment: I can offer even better analogies:
Something being a **dog**, definitely makes it an **animal**.

Something being an **animal** does not necessarily make it a **dog**

Comment: I have millions of them, but you get the point. And now I'm talking to myself :-D